# javscript Returning id value to another function is not working

Tags: javascript, html

i'm making a sudoku for a toy project. What i'd like to do is returning id value of blanks and putting it to another function. So when i click the number i want it to get putted in blanks but it doesn't work. Can you guys help me what's the problem?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    div {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="item" id="su1" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id()"></div>
  <div class="item" id="su2" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id()"></div>
  <div class="item" id="su3" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id()"></div>

  <div class="number" id='num1' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value()">1</div>
  <div class="number" id='num2' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value()">2</div>
  <div class="number" id='num3' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value()">3</div>

  <script>
    function change_id() {
      var idname = event.target.getAttribute('id');
      return idname;
    }

    function put_value() {
      var get_num_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
      var num = document.querySelector('#' + get_num_id);
      document.querySelector('#' + change_id()).textContent = num.textContent;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is thing you are missing is you have to pass an JavaScript event object from your .html file when function is click and catch the event on function parameters you can use the following code:

```
<div class="item" id="su1" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id(e)"></div>
<div class="item" id="su2" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id(e)"></div>
<div class="item" id="su3" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id(e)"></div>

<div class="number" id='num1' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value(e)">1</div>
<div class="number" id='num2' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value(e)">2</div>
<div class="number" id='num3' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value(e)">3</div>

<script>

 var changedId = null; // we create a variable which stored the changed id value

 function change_id(event){
  changedId = event.target.getAttribute('id');
 }

 function put_value(event){
  var get_num_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
  var num = document.querySelector('#'+get_num_id);
  document.querySelector(`#${changedId}`).textContent = num.textContent;
 };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now :))) i didn't know i should use 'null'. Mind if i ask a one more question?  Why can't i use return to get id value?

Comment: Install of null you can use empty string or any things to initialize variable since as far as i know it's not a good practice to initialize variable like this `var changedId;` we should kept any things like null or empty strings or a initial value.

Comment: Now for your question,  when ever you call function `change_id(event)` it requires a actual item element which you get from the JavaScript event when you click on item element , so if you click on item element it store the id of the last clicked element globally and  when you click on number element it replace with it.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your point, when user clicked on filled/blank box we set its id and when user clicked on blank/filled box we fill blank box with filled `innerText` and also we unset both `id` variables to be ready for next round;

```js
let suId, numId;

function change_id() {
    suId = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    fill();
}

function put_value() {
    numId = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    fill();
};

function fill() {
  if (suId && numId) {
    document.getElementById(suId).innerText = document.getElementById(numId).innerText;
    suId = null;
    numId = null;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  cursor:pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid powderblue
}
```

```html
<div class="item" id="su1" onclick="change_id()"></div>
<div class="item" id="su2" onclick="change_id()"></div>
<div class="item" id="su3" onclick="change_id()"></div>

<div class="number" id='num1' onclick="put_value()">1</div>
<div class="number" id='num2' onclick="put_value()">2</div>
<div class="number" id='num3' onclick="put_value()">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

https://jsfiddle.net/9wovdsup/1/

JS

```
let app = function() {
    this.cellSelected = false
  this.$btns = document.querySelector('.btns');
  this.$items = document.querySelector('.items');
  this.$items.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.selectCell(e.currentTarget);
      this.checkSelected();
    });
  });
  

  this.$btns.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(this.cellSelected) {
        this.cellSelected.innerText = e.currentTarget.innerText
      }
    });
  });
}
app.prototype.checkSelected = function(el) {    
  this.$btns.querySelectorAll('.number').forEach(el => {
        if(this.cellSelected) {
        el.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
      el.removeAttribute('aria-disabled');
    } else {
        el.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
      el.setAttribute('aria-disabled', true);
    }
  });  
}
app.prototype.selectCell = function(el) {
    if(this.cellSelected) {
        this.cellSelected.setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
      this.cellSelected.classList.remove('selected');
      if(this.cellSelected == el) {
        this.cellSelected = false;
        return
      }
    }
        el.classList.add('selected');
    el.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
    this.cellSelected = el;
}

new app;
```

HTML

```
  <div class="items">
    <div tabindex="-1" class="item"></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="item"></div>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="item"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="btns">
    <div role="button" tabindex="-1" class="number btn" aria-disabled="true">1</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="-1" class="number btn" aria-disabled="true">2</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="-1" class="number btn" aria-disabled="true">3</div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve in a better way, as per I understood this would be the solution what you're expecting .

1. Closure is required to cache the function value and return later when ever needed.
2. same event object reference is representing when you execute the
   put_value function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    div {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="item" id="su1" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id()"></div>
  <div class="item" id="su2" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id()"></div>
  <div class="item" id="su3" style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="change_id()"></div>

  <div class="number" id='num1' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value()">1</div>
  <div class="number" id='num2' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value()">2</div>
  <div class="number" id='num3' style="border: 1px solid powderblue;" onclick="put_value()">3</div>

  <script>
    function change_id() {
    var idname = event.target.getAttribute('id');
    if(idname.indexOf('su') == -1){
        return change_id['cache'];
    }else{
        change_id['cache'] = idname;
    }
    }

    function put_value() {
      var get_num_id = event.target.getAttribute('id');
      var num = document.querySelector('#' + get_num_id);
    var change_id_val = change_id()
    if(change_id_val ){
            document.querySelector('#' + change_id_val).textContent = num.textContent;
    }
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can i ask you what is ['cache'] in change_id['cache']? or can i get a reference?

Comment: Well, functions also objects so we can store information in similar way like  in objects but its has to be accessed are assigned in Square brackets property access: object['property']
Here cache is property in a function(change_id) object , that's how closures works.
This technique is refereed as a Memoization.